# How do I create a build of dosbox with lptp/parallel port support

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, dosbox

I have a legacy application that seems to work okay under the latest version of `DOSBox` released/made `quix`. However, this application also requires support for LPTP ports. There seems to be a community of forks e.g. *MEGABuild (H-A-L-9000)*, *Uberbuild, Daum (ykhwong)* but a lof of these are out-of-date. How do I get a more build with parallel port support?

The problem I am having is that under these old forked versions of DOSBox the application I'm trying to run is unstable. So what I would like to have is an up to date fork of DOSBox with added LPTP support.

I've tested a lot of the forks and so far only `ykhwong's` implementation of the parallel extension seems to work for my purposes. In other forks, the printer reports as "*Printer not ready*", presumably because of implementation differences in how the printer is emulated in the dosbox layer.

Now I'm not familiar with the history of any of these forks, but I have noticed that for example, parallel configuration sections look alike to each other in respective ports. So I was hoping somebody had some pointers what I would need to apply if I were to take the current day source of DOSBox and how to get the parallel support in there that's in ykhwong's implementation.